# Parse email without Tmail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parsing

How would you parse an email without using using a library like TMail that does parsing for you using Ruby on Rails?

Comment: Not using a library like TMail or the Mail gem makes it very difficult to get the correct content. Email has all sorts of encoding options and formats and even then you will get emails that don't follow the standards. Why would you not want to use one of these gems?

Comment: I have been asked to do it without a library as an assignment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is for an assignment I will answer with some resources that outline the format email should take:

There have been several email specifications

- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822 - Outlines the first version (in 1982)
- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822 - Updated this (2001)
- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322 - Was the latest update (2008)

Depending on how much you actually need to implement I would suggest starting with the first as it was the simplest. These outline the patterns and format that the message will be in.

To start with you will find the headers then two carriage returns followed by the message body. There are a couple of options here. It's quite possible to start with regular expressions or even just pattern matching but it may be worth looking into Parsing Expression Grammars in more detail ([treetop](http://treetop.rubyforge.org/) for example).

I hope this gets you started.